# Custom assignment operator on standard library classes

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

For example, if I want to make the assignment

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> b;
a = b;  // a takes all the second components of the pairs in b
```

Is such a custom assignment possible?

Comment: `=` cannot be non-member: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators.

Comment: I want the overload because I used = in many places, and now that I've changed the left vector operand I will have to place the necessary transformation function everywhere I used =.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you overload `=` to get `a = b;` push all elements `second` to `a` ?

No. Other issues with overloading operators for `std` types aside, `=` can only be implemented as member function. You cannot add a member to `std::vector<int>`.

---

Can you overload `=` to get `a = b;` push all elements `second` to `a` ?

Yes. You cannot overload `=` for `std::vector`, but you can overload it for a different type:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>


struct pick_second_vector_ref {
    std::vector<int>& t;
    template <typename Source>
    void operator=(const Source& s) {
        for (const auto& e : s) {
            t.push_back(e.second);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> b {{"foo",42}};
    pick_second_vector_ref r{a};
    r = b;  // a takes all the second components of the pairs in b
}
```

However, this is just to illustrate what happens when taking your question too literally. As often a named function is much clearer than an operator overload that does something unexpected. The above `main` should rather look something like this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> b {{"foo",42}};
    copy_second(a,b); // no comment needed here because the code 
                      // explains itself !!
}
```

---

...ps...

> I used = in many places, and now that I've changed the left vector operand I will have to place the necessary transformation function everywhere I used `=`.

Ok. Go for it. Change the code. It will be simple fixes, because all occurences of `=` in your code are compiler errors. Remember: Code is written once, but read many times. The 5 minutes you spend fixing the `=` you will save on the long run when readers do not have to wonder what that `=` actually does (comments should only be needed to explain code when code alone cannot express it clearly, not the case here).

Answer (score 6):

What you seem to want is to *transform* one container to another. This is usually done with the suitably named [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) standard function:

```
std::vector<int> a(b.size());  // Set as same size as the source vector

std::transform(begin(b), end(b), begin(a), [](auto const& pair)
{
    return pair.second;  // Use the second value of each pair from the source
});
```

Comment: I probably would have gone with `std::back_inserter` instead of resizing, but this is the general answer

Comment: @MooingDuck That would lead to multiple reallocations of the data, better set the size once it's known.

Comment: `reserve` then. Resizing leaves problems if an exception gets thrown